# What should you use instead of UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize in iOS 9?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collectionView with a custom-spaced flowLayout. In iOS 10 and beyond, `UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize` works perfectly.

In iOS 9, using `estimatedItemSize` is breaking the layout, since the layout is using the values I pass to `estimatedItemSize`, even though they aren't accurate; they're estimates.

The size of the cells varies based on what comes back from the server, so they are all different.

`layout.estimatedItemSize` is being set in the collectionView's super's `init`.

How can I achieve a correct layout behavior in iOS 9?

Please let me know if I can clarify!

**Edit: With the accepted answer, I also used the intrinsicContentSize of the element I wanted to size.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement Following method:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout 
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```